# Openset of subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and relation with $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In ''Problems in Real Analysis: A Workbook with Solutions, Charalambos D. Aliprantis, Owen Burkinshaw, Academic Press, 1990'' pp. 134, problem 16.4, in proof, the author claim that if $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of $E$, then exist open subset $V$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathcal{O}\cap E = V\cap E$. How i can proof this?

Comment: See the answer of WLOG and also notice that $O\cap E=O$  since $O$ is a subset of $E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of subspace topology: $O  = O \cap E $ is open in $E$ with the subspace topology if and only if there exists an open set $ V \subset \mathbb{R} $ such that $$O = V \cap E$$